# Make a Simple Cross Platform Program

Tags: windows, macos, cross-platform

I was wondering how I could make a simple cross platformed program. What I mean is, I want to make a program that edits iPad/iPhone files easily. I am not sure how to make this. What do I use so like it checks if you have an iPad connected and which iPad to use. Also, what I mean by simple is like all it is is buttons and texts and maybe some pictures. Sort of like Visual Basic. Is there a program that does both of what I am asking for or would I need 2 separate programs? If you don't understand what I am asking, please just say so, because I would really like to make this app. Thanks! Btw, I have a Mac, so if you could suggest Mac programs I could use. :)

Comment: What do you mean by "ipad/iPhone files"?

Comment: There are some files that can be edited on an iPad/iPhone, such as .json and .plist and I figured out a hack for a game on the iPad/iPhone, so for educational purposes (I will not be distributing this program), I would like to try to make a program that detects if an iphone or ipad is connected, then when you press on one of the buttons, it will edit one of the files on the ipad, because that button has the code to edit that certain file. Is it even possible to open, edit, and save a file with coding? Thanks!